# Regex Compilation Failed Nothing To Repeat

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to run a regex compilation to find a price. The price has some leading text, a possible space, opens a span which can have many different variables which are unimportant, then the span closes and there is a possible dollar sign followed by the price.

My regex is this:

`"@minimum bounty amount is\s*<span[^>]*>\$?[\d,]+@"`

The `@` is my delimiter, I have the trailing words, the possible space, the span opens, I say "Don't worry about anything until you get to the end of the tag", the tag closes, I have the possible dollar sign and then I have it match numbers and commas as the number can and likely is formatted with commas.
The error I get is this:

`Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 41`

In theory this regex should match something like `The minimum bounty amount is <span style="white-space: nowrap;">$50</span>` and on the Notepad++ regex engine it is matching this. However PHP seems to not like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is use of double quotes. PHP will be sending `$` unescaped to regex engine.

Try with single quote:

```
'@minimum bounty amount is\s*<span[^>]*>\$?[\d,]+@'
```

Double quotes will require double escaping the `$` as:

```
"@minimum bounty amount is\s*<span[^>]*>\\$?[\d,]+@"
```

1st escaping is for PHP and 2nd escaping is for regex engine.

Comment: Very good point. That seemed to solve it. Thank you very much!